# Stripe form not showing properly

Tags: stripe-payments

My Stripe Form isn't showing properly. Here is the screenshot.

[image]

I included the stripe script tag in my head tag. Added the form and the css and javascript per instructions in stripe docs. 
I thought maybe some other links or scripts are overwriting the stripe script so I tried to uncomment them, but nothing changed the stripe form.

I also made sure than my classes aren't overwriting each other.

```
<head>
...

<!-- Stripe  -->
    <script src="https://js.stripe.com/v3/"></script>
...
</head>

<body>
...

<form action="/charge" method="post" id="payment-form">
   <div class="form-row">
      <label for="card-element">
         Credit or debit card
      </label>
      <div id="card-element">
      <!-- A Stripe Element will be inserted here. -->
      </div>

      <!-- Used to display form errors. -->
      <div id="card-errors" role="alert"></div>
   </div>

   <button>Submit Payment</button>
</form>

...
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out. I just ended up making my own styles tho it took some time.